# what is the purpose of using JSON in android?

Tags: android, json

I need to know the purpose of using **JSON** in android ?

Please anyone tell me in a simple way...

Thanks

Comment: a way or a purpose ? ... Question unclear.

Comment: whenever you wish to serialize a javascript object, e.g. for 'later'  reuse? (think `localStorage`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is very light weight, structured, easy to parse and much human readable. JSON is best alternative to XML when your android app needs to interchange data with your server

Answer (score 1):

The same reason you'd use it on any platform. JSON is a way of storing and expressing information. It uses attribute-value pairs in a hierarchical structure. In Android specifically, you may need to download some information from a database, which could be stored in JSON and then read by your app. Alternatively, you could store data locally in JSON but there are probably better and more efficient ways to do that if you're not sending data across a network.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: This answer is right. Of corse, using JSON from a language like JavaScript sounds a more "natural" choice, but you can use it as a universal data transport format.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can get data Json if you work with database. Or if you work with some API's then you can get data in format Json.

Answer (score 0):

For example an app could fetch data from a server. When using JSON to get the data, the traffic is quite small and the app can easily work with it.
For example you have a server with a database with recipes, and your app displays recipes, the app could ask the server for recipes, and it gets a JSON in return. for example:

```
{
    name: 'Cookies'
    ingredients: { 'Butter', 'Eggs', ... /* I don't know, I'm not a chef :D */
    ...
}
```

The app can then just read the properties and display them in a neat list ;)

Answer (score 0):

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight format that is used for data interchanging. It is also a subset of JavaScript's Object Notation (the way objects are built in JavaScript

Pls go through this link: http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation
JSON is lightweight text-data interchange format
JSON is language independent *
JSON is "self-describing" and easy to understand
*   JSON uses JavaScript syntax for describing data objects, but JSON is still language and platform independent. JSON parsers and JSON libraries exists for many different programming languages.

Comment: Thanks...useful link  http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON in Android is not different than using it on any other platform. The main advantage of the format (in comparison to XML for example) is the small size of the data. This is very important for mobile devices due to the scarce resource those application use - i.e. your mobile app should be able to run with little memory usage, slow internet connection and so on.

Besides Android's framework has built-in tools for parsing / creating JSON objects. Thus it is both easy and efficient to use JSON rather than XML. If you have any project specific reason to prefer another data presentation format - don't worry. It is perfectly fine NOT to use JSON as long as some other format is more suitable for your project.

In short JSON is usually the right choice due to its small footprint and easy of use.